# Struts2.3.16 to struts 2.3.25 - Dependency jar files that needs to be changed?

Tags: struts

The web application uses struts2-core-2.3.16.3. Since Apache struts 2.x before 2.3.25 have vulnerability with cross site scripting, we need to migrate to struts2.3.25 and above. Not sure on the dependency jar files. Please advise on the jar files that needs to changed apart from struts2-core-2.3.16.3.

Comment: http://www-us.apache.org/dist/struts/2.3.28.1/struts-2.3.28.1-min-lib.zip

Comment: want to try with 2.3.25. Please let me know the link for 2.3.25 min libraries. I couldnt find a valid one.

Comment: There is no such version as 2.3.25.